# Dynamically set axis limits and scaling for 3D plots in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to build a script that can take in strings representing math functions and plot them. The problem I'm encountering is that due to the wide range of possible inputs to be plotted, the scaling and limits that work for some functions will not work for other functions. If I plot a sphere or torus, using set_aspect("equal") prevents them from looking warped. For another function set_aspect("equal") MAKES it look warped.If I plot a sphere with radius 100, due to my x and y linspace it looks fine. If I set it to radius 10 it looks puny. I don't know how to go about setting things up to handle wide ranges of functions.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sympy
import numpy as np



def queryMatplotlib3dEq(sol, ax):

    lhs, rhs = sol.split("=")

    def f(x, y):
        if (lhs == "z"):
            return eval(rhs)
        else:
            return eval(lhs)

    x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
    y = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    if (lhs == 'z' or rhs == 'z'):
        Z = f(X, Y)

    max = 0 
    for i in range(0,len(Z)):
        for j in range(0,len(
            Z[i])):
            if(Z[i][j]> max):
                max = Z[i][j]
   



    print(max)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="viridis")
    #For some functions that are huge, set_aspect('equal') makes them warped
    if (max > 1000) == False:
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
       
    # xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    # ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
    # ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
    # print(xmin,xmax)


#With set_aspect('equal') these looks great, without it they look warped
# qVal = "(8- (x**2 + y**2)**(1/2))**2 + z**2 = 3"
# qVal="x**2+y**2+z**2=1000"
# qVal="x**2+y**2+z**2=10"

# #With set_aspect('equal') this looks terribly warped, without it it looks great
qVal="x*y**3 -y*x**3"


# qVal="x**2 + y**2"



x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x y z')

if ('=' in qVal):
    lhs, rhs = qVal.split('=')
    eq = sympy.Eq(eval(lhs), eval(rhs))
else:
    eq = sympy.Eq(eval('z'), eval(qVal))


sols = ['z=' + v.replace('sqrt', 'np.sqrt')
        for v in map(str, sympy.solve(eq, z))]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

for sol in sols:
    
    queryMatplotlib3dEq(sol, ax)


plt.show()
```